# WPF Canvas Mouse Events have disappeared

Tags: wpf, canvas

I had a WPF app which drew some geometry on a Canvas.   Today I needed to add a Region Of Interest (ROI) rectangle which I initially did using the same canvas just for debugging.    The Mouse Event handlers are used to draw the rectangle . . .

```
     <Canvas Name="cnv"  Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0"  Margin="10,21,315,251"
      MouseDown="cnvMouseDown" MouseUp="cnvMouseUp" MouseMove="cnvMouseMove" />
```

... That worked OK so I decided to move the ROI rectangle code to a separate Canvas overlaying the original one so I could delete and redraw the rectangle without disturbing the other geometry on the first Canvas.
... so now I have this . . .

```
        <Canvas Name="cnv"  Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Margin="10,21,315,251"
     MouseDown="cnvMouseDown" MouseUp="cnvMouseUp" MouseMove="cnvMouseMove" />

        <Canvas Name="ROIcnv" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Margin="10,21,315,251"
 MouseDown="ROIcnvMouseDown" MouseUp="ROIcnvMouseUp" MouseMove="ROIcnvMouseMove"/>
```

... but now **NONE** of the mouse event handlers for either Canvas get triggered when I click or move the mouse.    Note that the only ones I care about are the ones on the second canvas, i.e., the ROIcnv... ones.

Comment: You'll have to set the Background property of the Canvas (e.g. to Transparent), otherwise it won't get any mouse input.

Comment: BIngo!   That was it!   (what does having a color to do with receiving mouse events?)  Thanks!